# Applications of Keisler–Shelah's Theorem

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, model-theory

Look at the following theorem.

**(Keisler–Shelah Theorem)** Two $L$-structures $M$ and $N$ are elementarily equivalent if and only if there is an index set $I$
and an ultrafilter $D$ on $I$ such that $\big(\prod M\big)/D \cong \big(\prod N\big)/D$.

Keisler–Shelah Theorem is an interesting theorem for me but I have not seen any application of it.

Is it easy to use this theorem to show, for example, $(\mathbb{Q},<)$ and $(\mathbb{R},<)$ are elementarily equivalent?

Comment: Even if you could show that $(\mathbb Q,\lt)$ and $(\mathbb R,\lt)$ are elementarily equivalent by showing that they have isomorphic ultrapowers (seems like a hard way to do it), that wouldn't be an application of the Keisler–Shelah theorem, it would be an appication of Łoś's theorem. What Keisler and Shelah showed was that elementarily equivalent structures have isomorphic ultrapowers; everybody already knew the converse, which is much easier

Comment: One "application" of the Keisler–Shelah theorem is that the relation "$M$ and $N$ have isomorphic ultrapowers" is transitive. But then you can ask, what applications does that transitivity result have?

Answer (score 4):

As was pointed out in the comments, the direction "isomorphic ultrapowers -> elementarily equivalent" is really Łoś's theorem (and is much, much easier to prove than the converse).

So we should look for cases where the direction "elementarily equivalent -> isomorphic ultrapowers" can be used.  To save some notation, let me write $M^{\mathcal{U}}$ for the ultrapower of a structure $M$ by the ultrafilter $\mathcal{U}$.

The applications I know of are typically of the following form: You're interested in some operation, let's call it $\sigma$, which turns structures of some kind into structures of another kind, and you want to show that if $M \equiv N$ then $\sigma(M) \equiv \sigma(N)$.  You know that $\sigma$ commutes with ultrapowers, that is it has the property that $\sigma(M^{\mathcal{U}}) \cong (\sigma(M))^{\mathcal{U}}$.  Then if $M \equiv N$ you have an ultrafilter $\mathcal{U}$ such that $M^{\mathcal{U}} \cong N^{\mathcal{U}}$, and therefore $(\sigma(M))^{\mathcal{U}} \cong (\sigma(N))^{\mathcal{U}}$, so $\sigma(M) \equiv \sigma(N)$.

A specific example of this type is when the original structures are fields, and you want to prove that if $F \equiv K$ then $GL_n(F) \equiv GL_n(K)$.  Some details about this example, and links to more of this kind, are in the top answer to this MO post: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/158583/is-it-ever-a-good-idea-to-use-keisler-shelah-to-show-elementary-equivalence.